# Can I create an event in a trigger?

Tags: mysql, events, triggers

Is it possible to create a new event from inside a trigger?
It's not something I'd particularly recomment, but I'm just wondering if it can be done.

I would like to fire a insert in response to an update, but have the insert be done delayed.
Right now I insert a value into a temp table and have a predefined event sweep that table every x minutes.

However this seems wasteful because most of the time there's nothing to do.
If I cannot create the event, can I at least enable/disable it on the fly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot **create** an event from a stored procedure or trigger.

*>If I cannot create the event, can I at least enable/disable it on the fly?*

```
ALTER EVENT event1 ENABLE;
ALTER EVENT event1 DISABLE;
```

[CREATE EVENT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html)

Comment: thanks for the reply, does that implicate that it's impossible to create an event inside a trigger?

Comment: Yes, it is impossible from the trigger or from the stored routine.

Comment: So the only way to dynamically schedule an event to occur upon insertion of a record is to do it from the application side by sending a create event query. Allowing the creation of events within triggers would make it really easy to create event-driven scheduled tasks as an alternative to polling based cron commands! (This is useful for future events that needs to occur at second resolutions.)