# Can i create/alter an event after a query in mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

i'm searching a way to create/alter an event after a query (for data) in mysql and i want to ask you if it possible to do it.

I found [How to alter an event in mysql which is already created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12780997/how-to-alter-an-event-in-mysql-which-is-already-created) , that don't answer my question fully. I'd like not to send a query from my application to the server to alter the event, i prefer the server itself to change the event after the query.

I was thinking of doing it with an after insert trigger, but i found [Can I create an event in a trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510494/can-i-create-an-event-in-a-trigger). It's not possible to create an event in a trigger.

I'm stuck, do you have any suggestions?

What i'm trying to do is to send a query to insert some data, in which there is a date i want to use in the AT clause of the event.
I'm using mysql-workbench, i'm not sure if it's usefull to know it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to include a detailed description of what you want to do. Include the table structure and the data of that tables you have. Based on these tables/data describe what you want to do. Also check https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Comment: Maybe you could change your approach and create a procedure, that will take the date, insert it into the table and alters the event.